# Merge two documents based on common id in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

How to access query string parameters in serverside javascript in MarkLogic.

The scenario is that I am using Transformers and I want to search documents based on the values given in the URL:

```
http://localohst:port/latest/qbe?query={$query:{"k","v"}
```

I want to search documents using k,v in javascript function dynamically.

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the formatting, making it more readable. Remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit questions to improve them as much as possible - so if you have any more information to add, please do.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the jsearch API. It uses cts.query for search input, but it includes conversion of a QBE into a cts.query.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript#chapter

The following topic covers using QBE with jsearch:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript#id_99182

And you can find the top level of the API function reference for jsearch here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/js/jsearch